# i am getting nothing in emulator after changing the date using RECEIVERS

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have this , .xml file .... to present my whole code

```
<receiver android:name=".broad_2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>



<activity
    android:name=".the_rock_iss"
    android:label="time_change_hua" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HO_HO_HO" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

& i have used this receiver to find that my date is changed , in the device

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
    {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.example.time_change_ho_tho_activity_start_ho", "com.example.time_change_ho_tho_activity_start_ho.the_rock_iss");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);       

    }
}
```

& from this receiver , i want to **open my activity** .
which is .... not displayed in emulator after changing the date !

```
public void onCreate ( Bundle bun )
{
    super.onCreate(bun);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

& for this i have this .xml file , to present the user interface .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are getting nothing because you will only fire your intent at the exact moment that the date changes. From what I have understtod from your question you are setting up the emulator, then rerunning it with a different date. I think if you put this on you phone over night then your `onRecieve()` will be triggered.

Comment: i think , no ..... because in the place of DATE_CHANGED .... i tried for , POWER_disconnect and it does'nt work !